# Positioning button inside leaflet layer control

Tags: javascript, button, leaflet

I'm using the [leaflet styled layer control plug in](https://github.com/davicustodio/Leaflet.StyledLayerControl) to customize my map control.

I'm trying to add a button to the top right corner of my controls that closes the controls (primarily for mobile use).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584613/manually-close-layer-control-window-javascript) and it works, but now I'm wondering how I can position this button. I want it to be in the top right corner of the control.

When I position the class "leaflet-control-close" it works (I tested with "position: relative; float: right;" and it did float right but stayed at the bottom), but if I give it an absolute position at the top of the page it seems to be appear behind my overlays.

I want it to push down the overlays a little bit so that it doesn't overlap.

EDIT: [here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ailisg/mggn928e/7/) showing what's happening. It's a little convoluted because the styled layer control files don't have a CDN so I just pasted in the CSS and javascript. I made a note where I add the button in the original Javascript, and below that JS is the JS to create the map and overlays.

I know the button on a desktop is kind of annoying because when you close the control with it, it immediately pops back open because your mouse is hovering. In my actual code I've set the display to none if the screen width is larger than tablet size, because that's the only time I feel like I need the button.

I customized the styled layer control javascript in order to include the button:

```
L.Control.StyledLayerControl = L.Control.Layers.extend({

    onAdd: function(map) {
        this._initLayout();
        this._update();
        this._addButton();

        map
            .on('layeradd', this._onLayerChange, this)
            .on('layerremove', this._onLayerChange, this);

        return this._container;
    },

    _addButton: function () {
      var elements = this._container.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-layers-list');
      var button = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'layer-control-close', elements[0]);
      button.innerText = 'Close control';
      L.DomEvent.on(button, 'click', function(e){
        L.DomEvent.stop(e);
        this._collapse();
      }, this);
    }
)};
```

Comment: Have to tried to use `z-index` ?

Comment: @Baptiste I have not, I'll try it just to see if it works, but really I'd rather the close button push down content a bit, I don't want it to appear stacked on top of the top overlay.

Comment: @Baptiste yeah z-index worked as it should, placing the button on top but it overlaps with the top overlay group. I can't use a margin to push the overlay group down because it adds a margin to each individual overlay group, spreading them all out.

Comment: Can you try to add a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Just added one to my question! @Baptiste

Comment: It's me or you haven't linked the jsfiddle ?

Comment: not you! my bad it's there now @Baptiste